# Given $\nabla f=(1,-1)$ fing $g(x)$ such that $h(x)=f(xg,g)$ is constant.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Given $\nabla f=(1,-1)$ fing $g(x)$ such that $f(xg,g)$ is constant, also $g(3)=1$.

**Attempt**

As $\nabla f=(1,-1)$, we have $f_x=1 \implies f=x+\phi(y)$ same for $f_y=-1\implies f=-y+\psi(x)$, substracting this two we get $x+y+\phi(y)-\psi(x)=0 \iff x-\psi(x)=-y-\phi (y)$ which implies that $x-\psi(x)$ is constant, and thus $\psi(x)=x+c \implies f=x-y+c$.

I then evaluate $f$ at $(xg,g)$ and get $h(x)=xg-g+c=g\cdot (x-1)+c$, as this must be constant, it's derivative must be $0$.

Then $h'(x)=g'\cdot (x-1)+g=0 \iff \frac 1{1-x}= \frac {g'}{g}\iff \ln|g|=\ln|1-x|+c$ as $g(3)=1$ we get that $c=\ln\frac 12$ and thus $|g|=\frac 1 2 |1-x|$, but after plugging this into $h$ I didn't get the right result.

Where did I scre up?

Comment: Oh thanks, I did forgot, but I did do it when integrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle\frac{g^{\prime}}{g}=\frac{1}{1-x}$, integrating gives $\displaystyle\ln|g|=-\int\frac{1}{x-1}dx=-\ln|x-1|+C$.

For $g(x)>0$ and $x>1$, this gives $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{a}{x-1}$, and $g(3)=1\implies a=2$;

so $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{2}{x-1}$ and $\displaystyle h(x)=f\left(\frac{2x}{x-1}, \frac{2}{x-1}\right)=\frac{2x}{x-1}-\frac{2}{x-1}+c=2+c$ is constant.

Comment: Damn, my arithmetic screw up was terrible. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad that helped.